# How do I use ARRAYFORMULA and IF to apply a script to an entire column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, zapier

I have little to no coding knowledge, so apologies if the solution is too obvious!

I am trying to add a Last Modified column to a Google Sheets file. To do this, I am using an AppScript function with the following code:

```
function setTimestamp(x) {
    if(x != ""){
        return  new Date();
    }
}
```

This works fine when I use `setTimestamp(x)` in my file. However, I am combining this with a Zapier action that creates a new row whenever new media is added. Every time a new row is created, any existing formulas are removed.

I assume I need to use ARRAYFORMULA to apply the `setTimestamp` formula to newly-created rows, but it must only apply to rows that aren't blank.

I have tried the following:

`={"Last Modified";ARRAYFORMULA(setTimestamp(A2:A))}` -> Only worked on first row

`={"Last Modified";ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B=setTimestamp(A2:A))}` -> Broke the file

`={"Last Modified";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A)=1,setTimestamp(A2:A),"")}` -> Expected 1 argument, got 3

Is there a way I can combine the IF into the script or a better way to solve the problem?

---

A public version of my file is available here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zkVRPr2Wh5bHjCT8cenInHnBk7qkMkuEMdwUxC_cRU/edit?usp=sharing

All data is dummy data and stock photos.

Comment: Try fix the brackets in `arrayformula` please.

Comment: `IF(A2:A=1,setTimestamp(A2:A),"")`

Comment: I expect `ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B=setTimestamp(A2:A))` to lead to infinite recursion or infinite creation of new rows. If you have use for it, try limiting the range first, later, there are functions that help terminating the implicit loop.

Comment: Hey Argyll, I tried this and got #ERROR

Comment: Unfortunately, `arrayformula` is not a true array map function. Even with native functions, it doesn't always work that way. But it's often worth a try. In order to handle array range, your custom function needs to handle array range directly. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: actually, the input rules are obscure enough to warrant some comment. I can draft an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `arrayformula` does not function as an array map function for custom functions. (Even for native functions where you may expect it to work that way, it does not always, sadly.)

To handle array range, we need the custom function to handle array range directly. That also limits the number of individual calls to custom functions, which materially saves execution time.

To handle array range, there are 2 ways. I'll comment on both.

###### Array range directly as input of custom function

1. If the input is a single cell, it is read directly
2. If the input range spans more than a single cell, the data is read as nested lists: a list of lists of rows.

For example, `A1` will be read as the data in `A1`. `A1:B2` will be read as `[[A1, B1], [A2, B2]]`.

You can remember it as *columns of rows*.

As for the input data format, numbers are taken **without the display format**. Texts are taken as strings.

If output is an array range, the result will automatically expend.

Thus, in your example, in B2 you can *almost* do

```
=setTimestamp(A2:A)
```

where `setTimestamp()` has been modified to

```
function out = setTimestamp(arr) {
    out=Array(mat.length);
    for (i=0;i<mat.length;i++){
        j=0
        if(arr[i][j] != ""){
            out[i]=new Date();
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

For more details, see the [official help page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). (Over the years, more details have become available.)

*Almost*, but not quite. For your direct question, above provides the answer. However, you seem to have an implicit requirement that your custom function is executed every time a new URL is found. Be careful that what happens here is that every time Google Sheet updates cell content, a new `Date()` is created and outputted.

###### Array range read within custom function

Since you know your URLs are in A2:A, and you want the output of your custom function to be B2:B, you can read and modify those ranges directly within your custom function via the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) Class.

In this route, you may find [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()), `getLastColumn()` in Sheet and [`getNextDataCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection) in Range convenient.

When you need to execute your custom function, you can run it manually or add `onEdit()` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to your custom function. (But `onEdit()` itself can mean substantial UI lag when using the sheet. It's usually more appropriate for sheets that parse external data automatically. See other triggers in the link for motions.)

In your example, you can *almost* do

```
function setTimestamp() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var row=1;
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();    
    while (row<=lastRow) {        
        if(cell.getValue()  != ""){
            sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(new Date());
        }
        cell = sheet.getRange(row,1,lastRow).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
        row=cell.getRow();
    }
}
```

which will scan for all URLs in A2:A and write current time to B2:B when executed.

Again, your example implicitly points to updating *only* when a new URL is found. So be careful about that. Use triggers as needed.

---

As for the need to place formula in B1, you can (and should) reference the output of your other application in a different sheet so that you or a different application of yours can edit without conflict.

Thus, for what was asked, we have everything.